# How to change a CSS class depending on if another CSS class combination is present?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to hide an element(.woocommerce_before_checkout_form) on my checkout page, but only at the login step(.wpmc-login). In other words: I want to hide an element depending on CSS class combination.

When they logged in they automatically go one step further in the checkout process and from there on I want to show the element(.woocommerce_before_checkout_form) again.

Every step in the checkout has its own set of CSS classes. And the active step has an additional class called .current.

I tried to stack the login classes with the .current class and then tried to address the .woocommerce_before_checkout_form class but it did not work. This is what I tried in CSS:

```css
li.wpmc-tab-item.current.wpmc-login + div.woocommerce_before_checkout_form {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Any ideas on how to do it in CSS or Javascript?

Here is the full code:

```html
<div class="woocommerce">
    <div class="wpmc-tabs-wrapper wpmc-tabs-wrapper-breadcrumb wpmc-tabs-clickable">
        <ul class="wpmc-tabs-list wpmc-4-tabs">
            <li class="wpmc-tab-item current wpmc-login"></li>
            <li class="wpmc-tab-item wpmc-billing"></li>
            <li class="wpmc-tab-item wpmc-shipping wpmc-not-clickable"></li>
            <li class="wpmc-tab-item wpmc-review wpmc-not-clickable"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="wpmc-steps-wrapper">
        <div id="woocommerce_before_checkout_form" class="woocommerce_before_checkout_form" data-step="step-review"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I found a solution that worked for me:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script>
if ( $( ".wpmc-login" ).is( ".current" ) ) {

    $( "#woocommerce_before_checkout_form" ).hide();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not possible with CSS based on your structure.

Comment: Okay thank you, do you know a solution in Javascript/JQuery?

Comment: he did try to code some css, but as you mentioned before, that won't work in this case @Paulie_D

Comment: I know...that's why **you** have to research Javascript or JQuery etc.

Comment: i've posted an anwser to give him a good start, its just not optimal in his case, as i said. it wont update the `.hasclass` to check all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this might be what your are looking for(a jquery solution):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let selectionDiv = $('.wpmc-login');
    if(selectionDiv.hasClass('active')){
        $('.woocommerce_before_checkout_form').css('display', 'none');
    }else{
        $('.woocommerce_before_checkout_form').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

since this will not always check the `active` class, you might want to change the `document.ready` into something like: `onclick`, or if you want to have it check it all the time, and don't link it to an event, google for an jquery observer(but that is quite overkill for this situation)

Comment: Thank you for the input, now I have a starting point to try something out as I only know very basic javascript.

Comment: no problem, for further questions(about this code) you can just comment here, i'd love to help you out

Comment: I fixed it using this line of code: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script>
if ( $( ".wpmc-login" ).is( ".current" ) ) {
 
    $( "#woocommerce_before_checkout_form" ).hide();
}
</script>` Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't forget you also have `.toggle`... so the 5 lines could be written as `$('.woocommerce_before_checkout_form').toggle(!$('.wpmc-login').hasClass('active'))`